# Is a neutral wire necessary between 2 circuits

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-design

Suppose I have 2 circuits with their own individual power supply.
Circuit 1 needs to send some sort of signal to circuit 2. Would I need to carry the current back to circuit 1 after the signal has reached circuit 2 (in the form of a neutral wire)? Couldn't I just send the voltage along one wire and then use the ground in the second circuit to complete the circuit, effectively having just one wire between the circuits?

Comment: You're assuming both circuits are referenced to a common, clean ground. That may or may not be the case. If not, unexpected and dangerous currents can flow if you connect even a single wire between the two circuits.

Comment: Please do not plan on using the mains wiring as a common for a low voltage signalling circuit.  It is not safe, reliable or even sure to work.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to try and understand why you need a common reference voltage (what you call "neutral", many call it "ground" or "common").

**The Voltage approach:**

What is a voltage? It's the difference in potential between two points. The key thing there is the number two.

If you only have one wire connecting between two circuits it will do nothing at all* because there is no reference for the signal. The ground in one circuit (which your signal is referenced to) has no relationship to the ground in the second circuit. In effect you can't apply a potential difference in the second circuit from the first.

**The Current approach:**

For a current to flow there must be a complete circuit. Without a second wire there is no complete current path between the two circuits. In essence you have a circuit consisting of a wire (the connection between the two circuits) and an infinite resistance (the second connection which you didn't make). The current through an infinite resistance will, by Ohm's law (\$V=IR\$) be zero regardless of the voltage.

Comment: This explanation is correct, however, if the 0V in both circuits is at ground level (like if both are running off of grounded DC power supplies), the 2nd 'wire' runs through one power supply, to the wall 0V/GND, and back out the other power supply. So, in certain cases you *can* get away without placing another wire in your circuit.

Comment: I think I understand what you're about the voltage approach, but isn't there just one ground (i.e. earth)? Why does the circuit care which ground the current is going to? As both circuits are connected to the mains, don't they have the same ground?

Comment: @dpdt if both are running of grounded DC supplies, then you have a second wire. If you have a second wire then that is not the situation described.

Comment: @MartinRand ground is a reference in a circuit. Connect an LED + resistor to a 9V battery, then the circuit has nothing to do with earth, but you would usually call the negative terminal of the battery your reference voltage (a.k.a ground)

Comment: If both circuits are connected to the mains, then you have more than one wire between them - the mains has three wires (or two if you exclude earth). But if you are running using supplies that are isolated, then the mains is no longer a reference because of the isolation.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, If ground is always 0v, then surely the reference is the same regardless of which ground?

Comment: @MartinRand Voltage, as explained in the answer, is **always between two points**. It is convention to define the ground as being at 0V and measuring voltages *relative* to ground, however, there is no law saying that this must be so. What I intended to say is that certain DC power supplies hold 0V at ground potential (based on the mains), so you form the 2nd wire that TomCarpenter was referring to *through the power supplies*. If you were to power both circuits off of batteries, then there would be no reason for both 0V's to be at the same potential, and you would have to place another wire.

Comment: @MartinRand ground is defined as zero **for the circuit**. Voltages aren't absolute. Take two circuits, both which consist of an LED connected to a 9V battery. In the first circuit I say that my reference (ground) is the negative terminal. In the second circuit though I say my reference (ground) is the positive terminal. Ground is just a reference, so there is nothing wrong with arbitrarily choosing where the reference is. Now how can you say that the 0V reference in both circuits is the same?

Comment: @TomCarpenter, oh dear, I'm really struggling here.
Where does the neutral wire end up? I always assumed it found it's way into the earth through the mains.

Is there anyway we could visualise this, or provide an analogy. I'm so confused.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, Oohhhh, I think it's just clicked. Let me sleep on it and I'll write up my understanding of it tomorrow. :)

Comment: @TomCarpenter, So are you saying that a reference is always relative to its own power source? I.e. the voltage coming from circuit 1 has no concept of the reference in circuit 2?

Comment: @MartinRand correct. With the two battery example, how can either battery know anything about the other battery without a common reference voltage (the second wire).

Comment: The thing to be aware of is as @dpdt says, some grounded power supplies connect the 0V pin to the earth ground (or some use neutral), meaning that the earth or neutral line may be providing the second reference wire which is why sometimes connecting two circuits together with one wire might actually work - it's not that it works with one wire, it's that there is a second wire somewhere else providing the reference.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, any chance you have a diagram to illustrate this?